# When applying patch SUPEE-5344 via ssh, "Not found" message appears

Tags: magento-1.9, aws

I tried to install the patch from the Magento root but the following errors come up:

```
PATCH_SUPEE-5344_CE_1.8.0.0_v1-2015-02-10-08-10-38.sh: 14: PATCH_SUPEE-5344_CE_1.8.0.0_v1-2015-02-10-08-10-38.sh: 127: not found
PATCH_SUPEE-5344_CE_1.8.0.0_v1-2015-02-10-08-10-38.sh: 14: PATCH_SUPEE-5344_CE_1.8.0.0_v1-2015-02-10-08-10-38.sh: 127: not found
PATCH_SUPEE-5344_CE_1.8.0.0_v1-2015-02-10-08-10-38.sh: 25: PATCH_SUPEE-5344_CE_1.8.0.0_v1-2015-02-10-08-10-38.sh: 0: not found
Checking if patch can be applied/reverted successfully...
-e ERROR: Patch can't be applied/reverted successfully.

checking file app/code/core/Mage/Admin/Model/Observer.php
Reversed (or previously applied) patch detected!  Assume -R? [n]
Apply anyway? [n]
Skipping patch.
3 out of 3 hunks ignored
checking file app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Request/Http.php
Reversed (or previously applied) patch detected!  Assume -R? [n]
Apply anyway? [n]
Skipping patch.
2 out of 2 hunks ignored
checking file app/code/core/Mage/Oauth/controllers/Adminhtml/Oauth/AuthorizeController.php
Reversed (or previously applied) patch detected!  Assume -R? [n]
Apply anyway? [n]
Skipping patch.
1 out of 1 hunk ignored
checking file app/code/core/Mage/XmlConnect/Model/Observer.php
Reversed (or previously applied) patch detected!  Assume -R? [n]
Apply anyway? [n]
Skipping patch.
2 out of 2 hunks ignored
checking file lib/Varien/Db/Adapter/Pdo/Mysql.php
Reversed (or previously applied) patch detected!  Assume -R? [n]
Apply anyway? [n]
Skipping patch.
1 out of 1 hunk ignored
```

Any idea ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Run via ssh  `sudo sh ./PATCH_SUPEE-5344_CE_1.8.0.0.sh -R`

Then run  `sudo sh ./PATCH_SUPEE-5344_CE_1.8.0.0.sh`

It seems the patch already included in the last release [1.9.1.0], but I've got the critical warninig message in the backend wired !